# Kibana - how to export search results

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, kibana-7

We've recently moved our centralized logging from Splunk to an ELK solution, and we have a need to export search results - is there a way to do this in Kibana 4.1? If there is, it's not exactly obvious.

Thanks!

Answer (score -15, accepted):

Sure, you can export from Kibana's Discover (Kibana 4.x+).
1. On the discover page click the "up arrow" here:
[image]

2. Now, on the bottom of the page, you'll have two options to export search results

[image]

At logz.io (the company I work for), we'll be releasing scheduled reports based on specific searches.

Comment: That exports the counts, but does not export the search results.

Comment: Note to others looking, this does not give a true export of what you are looking at as the UI suggests export does.

Comment: This feature doesn't appear to exist anymore (at least with Kibana 7.x).

Answer (score 51):

This is an old post.  But I think still someone is still searching for a good answer.

You can easily export your searches from Kibana Discover.

Click **Save** first and enter the "Title" field, then click **Share**

[image: Click Save first, then click Share]

Click **CSV Reports**

[image: Click CSV Reports]

Then click **Generate CSV**

[image: Then click Generate CSV]

After a few moments, you'll get the download option bottom right side.
The same report can be accessed from *Management* -> *Stack Management* -> *Reporting*

Comment: I saved but the button is still grey, letting me save again.. at last when I save without space in name it starts to work. Thanks!

Comment: If you miss the "Download" message on the bottom right (it is a transient message that disappears), you can always find your saved reports in Kibana -> Management -> Stack Management -> Reporting. The saved reports will have a "download" icon on the right side.

Comment: These CSV reports may be truncated to 10,000 records: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/15951

Comment: While using ElasticSearch a lot but almost not using Kibana at all... I had the missing step of creating an Index Pattern in Kibana prior to have the Discover tab actually show something.  At least on Kibana v7.8.1, Discover tab redirected back to the Dashboard when there were no Index Patterns created, which was very confusing trying to find something similar to your screenshot.

Comment: Is this in a specific version of kibana? In mine, there is no CVS reports option. There is only "save search" and "save object." The former is just a link to the filters and the other one is a link to a saved search. Neither allows for export of data.

Comment: @NellieK. Thanks.  I've added same on the answer.  So others can easily find it.

Answer (score 25):

This works with Kibana v 7.2.0 - export query results into a local JSON file. Here I assume that you have Chrome, similar approach may work with Firefox.

1. Chrome - open **Developer Tools /  Network**
2. Kibana - execute your query
3. Chrome - right click on the network call and choose **Copy / Copy as cURL**
4. command line - execute `[cURL from step 3] > query_result.json` . The query response data is now stored in `query_result.json`

**Edit:** To drill down into the `source` nodes in the resulting JSON file using `jq`:

```
jq '.responses | .[]  | .hits  | .hits | .[]._source ' query_result.json
```

Comment: This is crazy!  But works.  Also the `Response` tab will include the data as a json string.

Comment: Among network call names I choose "es" and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: LOL!! There is certainly a more proper way to do this, but +1 because I love "hacky" solutions as yours.

Comment: Do share the proper way, I'd take it over that hacky one if it works.

Comment: This seems to only return the first 500 results.

Comment: I struggled to find this, because I think the UI had changed since this answer was written. However, if you see a menu near the top that looks like `New Save Open Share Inspect Export`, click on `Inspect`, which opens a panel where you can click on `Response`. I did not find a URL, but I was able to copy the raw JSON.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to export the logs (not just the timestamp and counts), you have a couple of options (tylerjl answered this question very well on the [Kibana forums](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-export-logs-from-kibana-4/186)):

> If you're looking to actually export logs from Elasticsearch, you
>   probably want to save them somewhere, so viewing them in the browser
>   probably isn't the best way to view hundreds or thousands of logs.
>   There are a couple of options here:
>
> - In the "Discover" tab, you can click on the arrow tab near the bottom to see the raw request and response. You could click "Request"
>     and use that as a query to ES with curl (or something similar) to
>     query ES for the logs you want.
> - You could use logstash or [stream2es206](https://github.com/elastic/stream2es) to dump out the contents of a index (with possible query parameters to get the
>     specific documents you want.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60644447/430128 for a script that can do exactly this.

Answer (score 5):

@Sean's answer is right, but lacks specifics.

Here is a quick-and-dirty script that can grab all the logs from ElasticSearch via httpie, parse and write them out via jq, and use a scroll cursor to iterate the query so that more than the first 500 entries can be captured (unlike other solutions on this page).

This script is implemented with httpie (the `http` command) and fish shell, but could readily be adapted to more standard tools like bash and curl.

The query is set as per @Sean's answer:

> In the "Discover" tab, you can click on the arrow tab near the bottom
>   to see the  raw request and response. You could click "Request" and
>   use that as a query to ES with curl (or something similar) to query ES
>   for the logs you want.

```
set output logs.txt
set query '<paste value from Discover tab here>'
set es_url http://your-es-server:port
set index 'filebeat-*'

function process_page
  # You can do anything with each page of results here
  # but writing to a TSV file isn't a bad example -- note
  # the jq expression here extracts a kubernetes pod name and
  # the message field, but can be modified to suit
  echo $argv | \
    jq -r '.hits.hits[]._source | [.kubernetes.pod.name, .message] | @tsv' \
    >> $output
end

function summarize_string
  echo (echo $argv | string sub -l 10)"..."(echo $argv | string sub -s -10 -l 10)
end

set response (echo $query | http POST $es_url/$index/_search\?scroll=1m)
set scroll_id (echo $response | jq -r ._scroll_id)
set hits_count (echo $response | jq -r '.hits.hits | length')
set hits_so_far $hits_count
echo "Got initial response with $hits_count hits and scroll ID "(summarize_string $scroll_id)

process_page $response

while test "$hits_count" != "0"
  set response (echo "{ \"scroll\": \"1m\", \"scroll_id\": \"$scroll_id\" }" | http POST $es_url/_search/scroll)
  set scroll_id (echo $response | jq -r ._scroll_id)
  set hits_count (echo $response | jq -r '.hits.hits | length')
  set hits_so_far (math $hits_so_far + $hits_count)
  echo "Got response with $hits_count hits (hits so far: $hits_so_far) and scroll ID "(summarize_string $scroll_id)

  process_page $response
end

echo Done!
```

The end result is all of the logs matching the query in Kibana, in the output file specified at the top of the script, transformed as per the code in the `process_page` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you have troubles making your own request with curl or you don't need automatic program to extract logs from Kibana, just click 'Response' and get what you need.

After having troubles like 'xsrf token missing' when using curl,
I found this way is more easier and simple!

Like others said, Request button appears after clicking the arrow tab near the bottom.

[image: request button]

Answer (score 0):

Only the Timestamp and the count of messages at that time are exported, not the log information:

## Raw:

1441240200000,1214
1441251000000,1217
1441261800000,1342
1441272600000,1452
1441283400000,1396
1441294200000,1332
1441305000000,1332
1441315800000,1334
1441326600000,1337
1441337400000,1215
1441348200000,12523
1441359000000,61897

## Formatted:

"September 3rd 2015, 06:00:00.000","1,214"
"September 3rd 2015, 09:00:00.000","1,217"
"September 3rd 2015, 12:00:00.000","1,342"
"September 3rd 2015, 15:00:00.000","1,452"
"September 3rd 2015, 18:00:00.000","1,396"
"September 3rd 2015, 21:00:00.000","1,332"
"September 4th 2015, 00:00:00.000","1,332"
"September 4th 2015, 03:00:00.000","1,334"
"September 4th 2015, 06:00:00.000","1,337"
"September 4th 2015, 09:00:00.000","1,215"
"September 4th 2015, 12:00:00.000","12,523"
"September 4th 2015, 15:00:00.000","61,897"

Answer (score -1):

I tried the script but kept hitting some sort of spacing or hidden character problem.

I inspected the network (when I was on a bit of the kibana UI which just shows raw event logs), copied the request as curl. Converted it to python on a random website, then added the logic to extract and update search_after so that I'd get more than a single page worth of results.

Note that this is a little specific to CVAT (a computer vision image labelling software which uses Kibana to store its event data) but only to the extent that some of the API endpoints will be different for other Kibana instances.

It was just such a pain for me to get working that I really thought I should leave something behind.

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'PGADMIN_LANGUAGE': 'en',
    'sessionid': 'gqnwizma4m088siz93q7uafjygkbd1b3',
    'csrftoken': 'khLc0XNgkESvVxoPHyOyCIJ2dXzv2tHWTIoOcxqN6X6CR75E6VTzis6jRxNmVI43',
}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Origin': '<kibana-address>',
    'Referer': '<kibana-address>/analytics/app/kibana',
    'Sec-GPC': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/x-ndjson',
    'kbn-version': '6.8.23',
}

params = {
    'rest_total_hits_as_int': 'true',
    'ignore_throttled': 'true',
}

# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/search-multi-search.html
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68127892/how-does-search-after-work-in-elastic-search

results = []
for i in range(0, 500):
    
    if i == 0: 
        data = '{"index":"cvat*", "ignore_unavailable":true,"preference":1676572620990}\n{"version":true,"size":500, "from": ' + str(i*500) + ', "sort":[{"@timestamp":{"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}}],"_source":{"excludes":[]},"aggs":{"2":{"date_histogram":{"field":"@timestamp","interval":"1M","time_zone":"Europe/London","min_doc_count":1}}},"stored_fields":["*"],"script_fields":{},"docvalue_fields":[{"field":"@timestamp","format":"date_time"}],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":1673308800000,"lte":1676591999999,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"filter":[{"match_all":{}}],"should":[],"must_not":[]}},"highlight":{"pre_tags":["@kibana-highlighted-field@"],"post_tags":["@/kibana-highlighted-field@"],"fields":{"*":{}},"fragment_size":2147483647},"timeout":"30000ms"}\n'
    else: 
        search_after = f'"search_after": {str(search_after)}'
        print(search_after)
        data = '{"index":"cvat*", "ignore_unavailable":true,"preference":1676572620990}\n{"version":true,"size":500, ' + search_after + ', "sort":[{"@timestamp":{"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}}],"_source":{"excludes":[]},"aggs":{"2":{"date_histogram":{"field":"@timestamp","interval":"1M","time_zone":"Europe/London","min_doc_count":1}}},"stored_fields":["*"],"script_fields":{},"docvalue_fields":[{"field":"@timestamp","format":"date_time"}],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":1673308800000,"lte":1676591999999,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"filter":[{"match_all":{}}],"should":[],"must_not":[]}},"highlight":{"pre_tags":["@kibana-highlighted-field@"],"post_tags":["@/kibana-highlighted-field@"],"fields":{"*":{}},"fragment_size":2147483647},"timeout":"30000ms"}\n'
        
    #print(data)
    
    response = requests.post(
        f'<kibana-address>/analytics/elasticsearch/_msearch', #?from={str(i*500)}',
        params=params,
        cookies=cookies,
        headers=headers,
        data=data,
        verify=False,
    )
    
    print(i, response.status_code)
    
    if response.status_code == 500:
        break
        
    results.extend(response.json()['responses'][0]['hits']['hits'])
    search_after = results[-1]['sort']
```