# Accessing/querying Kibana from Python

Tags: kibana

I'm trying to access Kibana console from my python script since proxy don't allow me to access Elasticsearch in local but Kibana I can.

My intention is to run Elasticsearch queries with accessing Kibana locally to debug before deploying my application to server.

Here is what I have tried:

```
url = "myhost/myindex/_search"
query = '{"match":{"col1":"value"}}'
requests.get(url, verify="path", auth=(user, pwd), body=query)
```

This is returning http 200 but the content is showing a html page and I can't find my actual query response anywhere. Could some one help to find a way to get the query results.

Note: Elastic version is 7.3

Answer (score 2):

According to [Kibana's documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html), the simplest way is to use query parameters such as `q=col1:value`. If you want to use request body parameters, the proper structure is:

```
GET /my-index/_search
        {
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "col1": "value"
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Wildcards for indices also work: `GET /my-index-*` will do the search in all matching indices

Answer (score 0):

try following query

```
"query_string": {"query":"value","default_field":"col1"}
```

also you can try postman

Answer (score 0):

```py
from json import loads
from requests import post 
    
result = post(auth=(user, password), data=query, headers=HEADERS, url=URL)
result_json = loads(result.text)
```

You should already know what `user`, `password`, and `query` are. To find `HEADERS` and `URL` we will build on the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59771805/17628440) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040209/kibana-rest-api-redirects-to-login).

Use the Chrome Dev Tools to grab the URL; it will start with `https` and end with `proxy?path=_search&method=POST` or some such. Then in Chrome Dev Tools look at the request headers for your successful Kibana Dev Tools Console query. You want the one labeled `Cookie`. Then

```
HEADERS = {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'kbn-xsrf': 'true',
     'Cookie': your cookie goes here
}
```

And you should be good to go.