# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setting [index.lifecycle.rollover_alias] for index [job_temp_762226] is empty or not defined?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have created an index template in Elasticsearch, here are my settings

```
Index pattern
   job_temp* 
Priority
    None 
Component templates
    None
Data stream
    No 
Version
    None



{
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "lifecycle": {
          "name": "preview_policy"
        },
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "number_of_replicas": "0"
      }
    },
    "aliases": {
      "preview": {}
    },
    "mappings": {}
  }
}
```

After that I had created an index lifecycle policy, which automatically should delete these indices after 30 minutes,

```
PUT _ilm/policy/preview_policy
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "min_age": "0ms",
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_age": "30d",
            "max_primary_shard_size": "50gb"
          },
          "set_priority": {
            "priority": 100
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "30m",
        "actions": {
          "delete": {
            "delete_searchable_snapshot": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I created an index with pattern `job_temp_762226`, so according to my setting I was hoping it gets deleted after 30mins but instead I am getting this below error,

What am I missing here in order to make this work?

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setting [index.lifecycle.rollover_alias] for index [job_temp_762226] is empty or not defined
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ilm.WaitForRolloverReadyStep.evaluateCondition(WaitForRolloverReadyStep.java:77)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ilm.IndexLifecycleRunner.runPeriodicStep(IndexLifecycleRunner.java:176)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ilm.IndexLifecycleService.triggerPolicies(IndexLifecycleService.java:333)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ilm.IndexLifecycleService.triggered(IndexLifecycleService.java:271)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.scheduler.SchedulerEngine.notifyListeners(SchedulerEngine.java:184)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.scheduler.SchedulerEngine$ActiveSchedule.run(SchedulerEngine.java:217)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Comment: Did you carefully follow the steps [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html)?

Comment: @Val There's too much information given, I don't know what are all the options I need to use for my particular use-case. For example, do I need to create something called data-stream, I didn't do it since I didn't entirely understand the use case of it. Can you help on what are all the steps I need to do? I created template, I create index policy, I mapped template to the index policy. Can you tell me what I missed.

Comment: @Val My use-case, I just want to automatically delete indices that have a prefix `job_temp` after 30 mins.

Comment: @user_12 were you able to solve this problem? I am facing a similar problem. Kindly advise.

Comment: @phoenixSid I don't recall it but I switched to kibana to configure the things I needed and it worked just fine for me back then.

Answer (score 4):

Agree too much complicated settings just for that simple use-case.

For anyone got here just to solve that problem. You can completely **disable** roll-over on that policy. (It's commonly enabled by default in Advance Setting of Hot phase).

You just need to enable Delete phase within particular time since the index created.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what I had to do was:

1. Stop whatever was writing data and creating indexes
2. Delete old indices
3. Then execute the next commands:

#this command will create the alias for your index

```
POST _aliases
{
 "actions": [
{
  "add": {
    "index": "<index_name>*",
    "alias": "<alias_name>",
    "is_write_index": true
  }
  }
]
```

}

#this command will create the rollover_alias

```
 PUT /_index_template/<index_name>
{
 "index_patterns" : ["<index_name_patter>*"],
 "template": {
    "settings" : {
       "index.lifecycle" : {
           "name":"<lifecycle_name>",
            "rollover_alias": "<rollover_name>"
     },
  "number_of_replicas" : "0"
  }
 }
}
```

4. Associate the policy for your index if the command above didn`t work
5. Check if the rollover_name was created on the web GUI or in the settings, it cannot be empty like in the image
   [image: this should NOT be empty]
6. restart whatever was writing the data/creating indexes